# agora + Photon Voice = bad experience

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, photon, agora.io

Agora Video 2.92 Broadcast is being used inside of Unity with Photon Voice on iOS.
We are simply using Agora to broadcast a screen-share from a web app, we do not want any audio from from Agora as it is managed externally.

Upon entering/exiting the app, we now seem to either lose our microphone, or we lose speaker (or both) and can no longer hear other players in photon voice.

Is it possible for Agora to not adjust our audio settings? What should we be setting the default parameters to?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried calling disableAudio? It should cut off your audio and allow you to set your audio to Photon. Here is a link to the documentation about it. https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/disableAudio

Note- did you know that using agora for voice is easy to integrate in your project instead of photon voice? You can also have audio effects like voice changing and spatial audio. Also, Agora isn't geofenced like photon, allowing you a truly global low latency solution.